# Sonar separate quality profile per component

Tags: maven, cobertura, sonarqube

I have a multi-module maven project and have it's modules as Sonar components.

Is it possible to set alerts separate per module/component, or Sonar considers the whole project? If not, what's the best way of having my maven modules as separate projects in Sonar, so that mvn sonar:sonar is only executed once. I use cobertura for report generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment of writing this answer, that feature is not supported by Sonar. 
If separate metrics needed you need to create a separate project and trigger a separate build from Jenkins and providing specific pom.xml file for desired module.